# Can't start in VirtualBox; shows built-in shell

Tags: virtualbox

So I used the Linux Live USB creator and created a live usb checking the option to `Enable Launching LinuxLive in Windows` and after it was done and I ran `Virtualize_This_Key.exe`, and after a screen that said Ubuntu 13.10, all it showed was a console that said

```
"BusyBox v1.20.2 (Ubuntu 1:1.20.0-8.1ubuntu1) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list fo built-in commands

(initframs)"
```

Here's a [Screenshot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByvmTxeMh8oXZTZWbDBOTGZKa2s/edit?usp=sharing)

[image]

Comment: Something went wrong during the boot. What error message(s) do you see before this line?

Comment: The screenshot is in the link

Answer (score 0):

I had some similar problems my self.

It could be a hard drive problem (the virtual hard drive or your actual hard drive.) Might suggest deleting that VM you installed and starting over.

Also, if you have Ubuntu installed on ext4, that can cause some odd issues with the VM. Go into the settings for the for storage. The first option, IDE Controller, there is an option there "Use Host I/O cache" Make sure that there is a check in that box.